# Prevent my application from being suspended in background mode?

Tags: ios, background-process

My application is suspended by iOS after some time -- from one hour to several days -- but I want it to work in the background as long as possible (maybe infinitely) while the device is running. SMS will notify the user all the time that the device is running -- iOS doesn't kill the SMS service. My app has similar functionality and should notify user about the new income messages and so on.

So can I do the same with my application? Maybe there is some hack?

Comment: what user would want your program running at all times on their device?

Comment: @nathanhayfield My customer

Comment: @nathanhayfield BOINC, for example, is desired to run infinitely, and they really made it so.

Comment: SMS doesn't keep running in the background. It receives push notifications. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @vesper then that is a program I would never want to use.

Comment: @RileyE I'm trying to accomplish something similar to SMS.My app is a messenger

Comment: Then use push notifications. You can out find about them them [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/)

Comment: Use push notifications

Comment: You can't prevent app to kill or suspended, But you can achieve functionality to make it active for sometime to get your content using "Silent Push Notification". Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694963/what-is-silent-push-notification-when-does-the-device-receive-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

There are the following exceptions:

- Playing music
- GPS tracking
- VoIP

Also, all apps can get up to ten minutes to finish existing tasks.

There should be an answer if you're prepared to jailbreak, but otherwise, it's not possible with current versions of iOS.

The way around this is to do the processing on a server and send push notifications when something interesting happens.

Comment: You've said about the exceptions.Can I make my app a VoIP?

Comment: @AlexanderKaraberov It doesn't sound like you're building a VoIP application, so your application would be rejected by Apple for abusing Apple's background modes.

Comment: @AlexanderKaraberov Not unless it _is_ a VoIP app. (Put another way: yes, it will work but, no, Apple will reject it when they review.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want your application running indefinitely.

You should use [push notifications](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/). This will notify your user the same way the SMS application does.

Comment: Push notifications don't make apps stay in BG. silent push notification can awake the app from suspended state to BG state and they are very limited(only 2 or 3 silent notifications per hour are allowed by apple, rest is ignored). Trying to prevent your app being suspended with unsolicited ways will make apple reject your app.