# reason: 'Killing app because it never posted an incoming call to the system after receiving a PushKit VoIP push callback.'

Tags: ios, swift, voip, callkit, pushkit

I'm looking for solutions but I has find nothing yet. My app receives only VoIP pushes and after iOS 13 I'm not able to receive push when the app is in background mode anymore. I looked other questions but I was not able to solve my problem with solutions proposed.
There's someone who can help me?

> On iOS 13.0 and later, incoming Voice over IP calls must be reported when they are received and before the didReceiceIncomingPush() method finishes execution, using the CallKit framework, or the system will terminate your app.
>
> Repeatedly failing to report calls may prevent your app from receiving any more incoming call notifications.
>
> Basically, you can no longer use VoIP pushes for non VoIP messaging, and will need to use regular push notifications for those.

I read this announce but in my app for particular types of push VoIP I can't use function `reportNewIncomingCall()` because it requires params like: uuid, handle, hasVideo ecc.
And these params are not present in the payload.

Comment: You need to get these (the required params) in the calling void push.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the solution, VoIP pushes with these param are not received too when the app is in background mode

Comment: Since calls must be reported and these fields are required to report the call, you will have to modify the payload for the push.

Comment: Does the voip push indicate an incoming call?  If so the. You need to report that incoming call via CallKit. If it doesn't then you must use the normal push notification system.

Comment: I use both push incoming and push calls, also of the voip type, which are normal push. In both cases neither of them arrives in backgorund mode. The only way is to manage those that do not affect the call as normal pushes?

Answer (score 5):

Since iOS 13 you can only use VoIP pushes for reporting incoming calls. For pushes that are not incoming calls, you must use other alternatives (take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56788314/ios-13-killing-app-because-it-never-posted-an-incoming-call-to-the-system-after/57595700#57595700) here).

> Repeatedly failing to report calls may prevent your app from receiving any more incoming call notifications.

From my tests, it seemed to block all VoIP pushes after failing to report only 2 or 3 times, and it would stay blocked for around 24h.

> because it requires params like: uuid, handle, hasVideo ecc. And these params are not present in the payload

If you receive a VoIP push for a new incoming call, but stil don't have the required info you listed above, you can initialize the call with "dummy" values, and later update them. As for example, setting the remoteHandle to `CXHandle(type: .generic, value: "Connecting...")` and later updating it with the correct value:

```
cxCallUpdate.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .emailAddress, value: "email@mail.com")
cxProvider.reportCall(with: callUid, updated: cxCallUpdate)
```

Comment: Do you think this solutions is also for VoIP pushes that are not push call but only pushes with personalized payload?

Comment: You cannot use VoIP pushes for something other than reporting an incoming call. There is no way to do so.

Answer (score 3):

If you are implementing incoming call as another function and calling it as below. It won't work

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    yourIncomingCallFunction()
}
```

Instead Try Following :

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {

            print("didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload")

            if let callerID = payload.dictionaryPayload["callerID"] as? String,
                let hasVideo = payload.dictionaryPayload["hasVideo"] as? Bool{
                let update = CXCallUpdate()
                 update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: callerID)
                 update.hasVideo = hasVideo


                 let bgTaskID = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: nil)
                self.provider?.reportNewIncomingCall(with: UUID(), update: update, completion: { (_) in
                    completion()
                })
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(bgTaskID)
            }
        completion()
    }
```

This has Implemented the call provider posting call request inside the `pushRegistry:didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload with completion handler` function. This worked for me.

Try the VOIP request with terminal command:

```
curl -v -d '{"callerID": "test@test.com", "uuid":"YourUDIDorEmptyField", "hasVideo": false}' --http2 --cert yourvoipcertificatepemfile_Here.pem:pemfilePassword_Here https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/yourDeviceTokenID_generated_with_update_push_credentials_with_token_Here
```

**Replace:**

1. `test@test.com` with related details on `CXHandle.HandleType` 
   If it is your Callers Name (`.generic`) or email (`.emailAddress`) or phone number (`.phoneNumber`)
2. `YourUDIDorEmptyField` with your `UUID` or you can keep it empty as when `reportNewIncomingCall(with: UUID(), update: callUpdate)` has initialize `UUID()` in the code itself.
3. `"hasVideo" : false` here false is a `Boolean (true/false)` obviously that handles the `Audio / Video` call status on the incoming calling screen and you can use it to identify the call as exactly what type it is by implementing it.
4. `yourvoipcertificatepemfile_Here` is the name of your `.pem` file that you have exported from the voip certificate (`voipcertificate.cer` not directly but after generating from developer account and installing to your machine. Then in your `keychain -> mycertificates` **export** it as `.pem` file with a Password (`pemfilePassword_Here`).)
5. `pemfilePassword_Here` is your password that you have given when you are exporting `.pem` file from your installed voip certificate. (refer  to 4th point.)
6. `yourDeviceTokenID_generated_with_update_push_credentials_with_token_Here` should be replace with the `token` generated by following `Delegate` method of `PKPushRegistryDelegate`. See below.

   `func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry,didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {`

   ```
   let parts = pushCredentials.token.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }

   let token = parts.joined()
   print("did update push credentials with token: \(token)") }
   ```

If you have any concern please let me know. I have tried and tested this on App in foreground, background, lockScreen, and even after app removed from recent apps. 
**(iOS 13.4.1 and Xcode Version 11.4 (11E146))**

Answer (score 1):

This is not a payload issue. You can create your own payload. Just you have to call below function in this callback.

`func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void)`

Otherwise, Apple is blocking push notifications for a time.

```
provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update) { error in
completion() }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced same crash when tried using async version of `didReceiveIncomingPushWith`. The code I've used:

```swift
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType) async {
    guard type == .voIP else { return }

    let callUpdate = CXCallUpdate()
    let phoneNumber = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: "handle")
    callUpdate.remoteHandle = phoneNumber

    try? await callProvider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: UUID(), update: callUpdate)
}
```

It works fine when the app is in foreground, but is crashing in background. Logs show that for some reason it's not getting called at all.

At the same time completion version works fine:

```swift
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    guard type == .voIP else { completion(); return }

    let callUpdate = CXCallUpdate()
    let phoneNumber = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: "handle")
    callUpdate.remoteHandle = phoneNumber

    callProvider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: UUID(), update: callUpdate) { error in
        completion()
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude u saved my life, I was facing this problem for a week and can't figure out why my voip calls won't work on background

Answer (score 0):

iOS terminates app even it is not for iOS 13. Apple, itself says, it would terminate if the app is developed iOS 13 and later but still terminates app after fail to report. I've talked with Apple developer support, they said only iOS 13 would do that but still I got error.