# Call kit incoming call not getting triggered on Testflight build

Tags: voip, ios13, swift5, callkit, pushkit

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60828988/ios-13-reason-killing-app-because-it-never-posted-an-incoming-call-to-the-syst) code to build my app.. Actually it's working very fine on loose build but not on testflight build.. It would be great if anyone knows this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistakenly I was using the sandbox certificate, replaced it with the production certificate and it works.

Answer (score 0):

From backend environment change from development to production for TestFlight build(Voip notification\Callkit).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).