# Quickblox VOIP APNS comes on Background but app crashes

Tags: swift, call, voip, quickblox, videocall

I need help in ios sdk 2.17.4. in swift WebRTC projcet of ios voip push creates crash. Development team updated the sdk but this problem resolved in just objective c project.

I have raised this issue multiple time but support team never replied. I attached image of log issue.
When i checked this thing in objective c project it is in working but in swift it crashes.
[image]

Comment: You didn't actually attach any images, and please attach the actual data instead of image of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 13 Killing app because it never posted an incoming call to the system after receiving a PushKit VoIP callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56788314/ios-13-killing-app-because-it-never-posted-an-incoming-call-to-the-system-after)

Comment: Yes, I also got the same issue while received VOIP notification.

Answer (score 0):

QuickBlox Team has recently updated the Swift WebRTC sample, it contains an implementation example of voip push notifications management. You can download the sample [here](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat-webrtc-swift)

Comment: Yes of course i downloaded the project but still there is crash when voip background hit
"Killing app because it never posted an incoming call to the system after receiving a PushKit VoIP push callback."
and when i run objective c project it works and never crash.