# Is it possible to understand when a notification raised in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uilocalnotification

I know how to raise local notifications and show actions on it. When a user clicks on actions I can handle it on below method:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
 didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler 
 completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
   // Do something here
    if response.notification.request.content.userInfo["backUp"] {
     doBackUpHere()
     // Do other methods
    }
}
```

However, my situation is a little different. I need to do some functions when a notification raised before clicking on it or on it's actions(application is foreground or background). Other methods run when the user clicks on notification

```
func notificationRaised (notification: Notification){
  // to do if notification is 
  if notification.userInfo["backUp"] {
    doBackUpHere()
  }
}
```

**Update**

Please see @Sergey answer and our comments to understand better my propose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to make an action when a notification arrives, without any user input. If so, I suggest you take a look at [silent push notifications in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694963/what-is-silent-push-notification-when-does-the-device-receive-it) - they do just that, unfortunately - not showing in the user interface at all.

You could also experiment with local notifications on a timer, but remember that you can only run code when a user taps on a notification and/or one of its actions as the app is not guaranteed to be alive by the time a scheduled local notification is shown.

Comment: Yes, your understand my question correctly. [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html) says it is only for server notification. I need local notification. I have to turn on push notification that is not my goal.

Comment: @AmirShabani got it. So basically you can't do anything here as you will never know if your app is alive or not when you **actually send the notification**.

Comment: You mean there is no way to understand when notification raised? It can help me to know when a notification raised. Like broadcast receiver in android

Comment: @AmirShabani here's a quick clue. If it's a local notification, you're scheduling it yourself and so - you always know **when** you scheduled it, you have this data and you can save it locally to your app. The other thing is - your app might not be alive at this moment when notification is presented, so this info is useless if you can't actually execute any code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about ***'Silent push notifications'***? I think it is exactly what you are looking for ;) You can get that notification, do your stuff, and then show a local notification if you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I found for using silent push notifications I need to use push notification that is not my goal. Do you have a good resource for silent push notification.