# Laravel Push notifications: Send silent push notification

Tags: php, ios, laravel, push-notification, silent-notification

I am using [this](https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification) to send `push notification` to `iOS` and it is working fine except the fact that I don't know how to send a silent push using this package. I have tried to send it like this:

```
$payload = PushNotification::Message('', array(
                    'aps' => array(
                        'content_available' => 1,
                    ),
                    'data' => array(
                        'actionType' => $actionType
                    )
                ));
```

Sending empty string in the first param of `::Message`, it does not show anything on mobile screen but it does produces the sound. Secondly, I tried it without the presence of this param. But if this param is not present, it throws exception. How to send silent push? Any ideas?

My `Laravel` version is 5.4.

Comment: I guess it should be possible updating logic of ios app - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694963/what-is-silent-push-notification-when-does-the-device-receive-it

Comment: Practically, it is not feasible to send silent notification? let the device or the user operate this..

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave It is possible, but I don't know how to send it using the library I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave the link you provided in the comment above is to solve the issue if it is on mobile side but my issue is on server side.

Comment: You can set a silent mp3 file or something in server and can set here in your php code .. that is another way i guess.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave haha, I can do that but that's not the proper way of doing this.

Comment: I feel silencing the push notification is also not feasible as well :) you are breaking the user experience from my point of view.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave silent push is not for user, it is to send some data to the app on mobile to update something without user noticing it. when it is sent, the app is activated in background and the operation is done. So it has nothing to do with the user experience.

Comment: 'content_available' => 1, should work . dunno why .. though

Comment: try this .. `{
        "aps" : {
            "content-available" : 1,
            "sound" : ""
        }
        "customPayloadKey":3,
        "additionalPayload": {
                               "customKey":"customValue"
                             }
    }`

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave Nope, it isn't working.

Comment: 'content-available' should definitely work .. else there is something wrong

Comment: make sure its in INTEGER

Comment: `{
    aps = {
        "content-available" : 1,
        sound : ""
    };
}` TRY THIS .. SHOULD WORK...

Comment: `{
    aps =     {
        "content-available" = 1;
        "alert" = "";
    };
}`

Comment: `aps =     {
        badge = 7;
        "content-available" = 1;
        priority = 5;
    };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a trivial mistake that I made in the code shown above in the question is to use `content_available` instead of `content-available`.