# Swift: Getting Data from Remote notification

Tags: ios, swift, remote-notifications, silent-notification

I have a messaging app, which gets data from server through push notification.
In the following image, you can see the process and also check where it gets faulted:[image]

I have researched a lot about this problem but not getting a universal solution.

One solution I get is to use silent notification , [discussed Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694963/what-is-silent-push-notification-when-does-the-device-receive-it) , to get data before it is shown and save it. But I didn't find how to show notification from app delegate once I received silent notification.

Kindly correct me if I am conceptually wrong somewhere.

Update:
One of problem is that the *application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:* is only called when

1. app is in foreground
2. user clicks the notification

But when user **doesn't** click the notification, *application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:*  is not called, and I can't find a way to save the data, that is present in notification.

Comment: I don't think silent notifications is the solution you are looking for, since if I'm not mistaken they won't be called if your app is not in the background.

Comment: Alright then kindly suggest me the solution, if you think we can achieve required results from other way.

Comment: You may want to store the data you need in your backend and maybe make an API call to get this data once the app comes to foreground.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this question because even I am facing the same issue?

Answer (score 3):

There are two cases:

1. Background
2. Closed State

If the app is in `Background State`, you have to enable `Background Fetch`, then this method will be called when the app is in Background `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`

When the app is `closed` or `killed` by the user the above method not gonna work, for that you can use the `VoIP` technique.

`didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload` method will be called whenever Remote Notification arrives

[You can find more details about VoIP here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html)

Comment: I hope this approach is correct but only thing we need to consider for VOIP is our App should have the functionality which using the VOIP.

Comment: application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler, only runs when user clicks the notification, or when the app is in foreground.

If user dismisses the notification, I am unable to get the data.

Comment: application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHand‌​ler, it will called when app is in background also. Please check Remote Notification with background fetch

Answer (score 3):

Your question is "To get data from Remote notification while the App is in foreground" if im correct, You can use these two methods to get data from Remote notifications for background and foreground app modes.

```
//  Notification will present call back
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])

    // Handle your data here
    print("Notification data: \(notification.request.content.userInfo)")
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
//  Notification interaction response call back
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    // Handle your data here
    print("Notification data: \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")

}
```